# Move Files from Directory up one level

Tags: find, recursive, move

I have a filestructure with several subfolders where I'd like to search for all subfolder containing a certain string ("sub*") and then move all of the files in these found folders up one level from each of their respective location. And even potentially delete the then empty folder but I could do that with a second step as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find /path/to/base/folder/ -type d -name 'sub*' -exec bash -c 'mv {}/* "$(dirname {})"' \;
```

*NOTE*: this will not move hidden files (whose name start with `.`)

Comment: What is "dirname" in this supposed to be?

Comment: This is the name of a command, see `man dirname`

Comment: Okay, i tried it out. Unfortunately it does not do what I want. it moves the Folder found with "find" up one directory. However what i need is the content IN the folder to be moved up one level (so basically then on the same level as the folder)

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to -type f -execdir mv {} .. \;
```